# CentOS: Enabling GD Support in PHP Installation

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, gd, centos

How do I go about enabling GD Support in a CentOS Installation?

Comment: better on serverfault

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The thing that did the trick for me eventually was:

```
yum install gd gd-devel php-gd
```

and then restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly on CentOS release 6.5. The "phpinfo" page says that PHP has originally compiled without gd ('--without-gd') but also dumps a section about the now-present "gd".

Comment: Make sure that you are using the right php package. For example, in my case, I was using php56w, so I needed to use php56w-gd.

Comment: @EvanDonovan it's true only if you're using versions that are not in the official CentOS repository!

Comment: Thanks for that clarification @alfasin - I was not the person who did the upgrade of our PHP to 5.6, so I'm not sure why they used the php56w package. I just wanted to add that as a comment though in case anyone else gets dependency resolution errors.

Comment: Thanks @EvanDonovan!

Comment: if you're running PHP-FPM, instead of Apache, you need to restart PHP-FPM.

Comment: Thank you @EvanDonovan. My server admin uses php56w for some reason as well.

Comment: @alfasin that makes sense - we are using a different package of PHP because our CentOS was lagging behind. However, we are now on PHP 7.x - as should everyone be :)

Answer (score 34):

1. You need to find a repo that offers a GD lib matching your current php version. I've had great success using [Remi Collet's repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) for this purpose. In fact, I used it yesterday to update my php install to the latest 5.4.0RC6 version on my CentOS6 box.
2. Once you've setup the repo it's a simple matter of running `sudo yum install php-gd`
3. Of course, the usual things apply: make sure you restart apache after installing, etc.

Comment: If you have NginX, no need to restart! Apparently you need php-gd for WordPress "edit media" https://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit-media-not-working

Answer (score 6):

With CentOS 6.5+ and PHP 5.5:

```
yum install php55u-gd
service httpd restart
```

If you get an error like: `cannot map zero-fill pages: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0`, it could be because you don't have a swap file. I suggest you take a look at the tutorial mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20275282/828366

Tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-centos-6

Answer (score 5):

**CentOs 6.5+ & PHP 5.6:**

```
sudo yum install php56-gd

service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the command

```
yum install php-gd
```

and restart the server (httpd, nginx, etc)

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP7 on CentOS or EC2 Linux AMI:

```
sudo yum install php70-gd
```