# Call to undefined function imagettfbbox()

Tags: php, gd, freetype

I've installed PHP 5.5 on CentOS using the IUS repos and unfortunately I cannot use `GD` even after installing everything recommended:

```
Package php55u-gd-5.5.14-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gd-devel-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package freetype-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package freetype-devel-2.3.11-14.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

How would I go about enabling the GD text functions in PHP?

**/etc/php.d/gd.ini**

```
; Enable gd extension module
extension=gd.so
```

Comment: did you check if gd actually shows up in `phpinfo()` output, and restart Apache after installing the packages?

Comment: thanks for the reply, mark. yeah i did restart Apache and GD comes up under the `Module Authors` section and only there

Comment: I have just noticed an error when running php -a `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - libvpx.so.0: cannot map zero-fill pages: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0` not sure if this helps at all

Comment: Apparently GD needs swap space on CentOS, at least according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274938/php-gd-library-installed-but-not-functioning-on-centos-6-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed when running `php -a` that there was an error saying `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - libvpx.so.0: cannot map zero-fill pages: Cannot allocate memory in Unknown on line 0`. Due to this being a production system I don't have errors showing on the webserver but I do feel stupid now.

I traced the error back to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274938/php-gd-library-installed-but-not-functioning-on-centos-6-4) on StackOverflow which informed me I needed swap space on my VM which I fixed by running:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Well done to [cOle2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61779/cole2) for spotting this whilst I was writing this up.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290958/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagettftext)

"According to the PHP manual entry for imagettftext():

This function requires both the GD library and the » FreeType library.

You must be missing one or both of the required libraries in your PHP build."

Comment: I've double checked and have both the FreeType and GD libraries, thanks for the answer, though

Comment: maybe you need to compile from source